# Ballerina splitting of a string with the delimiter the end

Tags: ballerina

When using the `regex:split` and the `regexp:split` two different results are provided when a string which has the delimiter at the end is used. For example consider the following code,

```golang
import ballerina/regex;

public function main() {
    string msg = "abc|def|ghi|";

    string[] splitsRegex = regex:split(msg, getwithescape()); // ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
    string[] splitsRegexp = re `${getwithescape()}`.split(msg); // ["abc", "def", "ghi", ""]
}

function getwithescape() returns string {
    return "\\|";
}
```

Which is the correct behaviour?

Comment: Using r`egexp:split` is the correct way since Ballerina Swan Lake Update 8 (2201.8.0).

Answer (score 2):

The `ballerina/regex` is deprecated and is no longer being used. The result provided by the  `regexp:split` is correct.

```
re `${getwithescape()}`.split(msg)
```

Ballerina `regexp` follows the ECMAScript language specification. According to the ECMAScript, the above split should return an empty string at the end.

More details of regexp:split can be found on [Ballerina regexp:split](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.regexp/2201.8.2#split)